# Generate a thin JAR with external dependencies using SBT

Tags: scala, google-cloud-functions, sbt

Is there an easy way or a plugin to generate a thin JAR with external dependencies using SBT? Keep in mind that the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file should contain the full list of libraries in the `Class-Path`

What I need is something compatible with the [Google Cloud Functions thin jar](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/java-deploy#build_and_deploy_a_thin_jar_with_external_dependencies).

At the moment, I'm using Uber jar, but I would prefer to use this other format.

I looked into sbt-assembly and sbt-pack, but not lucky. If they are the solutions, could you provide with an example or link?

Comment: Is kind of funny that everyone always ask the opposite, since most people just try `package` first and get surprised that the JAR is not runable.

Answer (score 1):

The following is a rough translation of the Gradle example

```
ThisBuild / version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"

ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.13.11"

lazy val prepareDeployment = taskKey[Unit]("prepare the deployment")
def filename(f: Attributed[File]): String = filename(f.data)
def filename(f: File): String = f.toPath.getFileName.toString

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "sbt-package-example",
    libraryDependencies += "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.15.2",
    Compile / packageBin / packageOptions += {
      def filename(f: Attributed[File]) = s"lib/${f.data.toPath.getFileName}"
      val dependencies = (Compile / dependencyClasspathAsJars).value
      Package.ManifestAttributes(
        "Class-Path" -> dependencies.map(filename).mkString(" ")
      )
    },
    prepareDeployment := {
      val mainJar = (Compile / packageBin).value
      val dependencies = (Compile / dependencyClasspathAsJars).value
      IO.copyFile(mainJar, target.value / "deployment" / filename(mainJar))
      for (dependency <- dependencies) {
        IO.copyFile(dependency.data, target.value / "deployment" / "lib" / filename(dependency))
      }
    }
  )
```

Running the following command

```
sbt prepareDeployment
```

will create a `deployment` directory under `target`, containing the main JAR without dependencies and a `lib` directory in there with all the dependencies.

The `MANIFEST.MF` file for this example contains the following line:

```
Class-Path: lib/scala-library-2.13.11.jar lib/jackson-databind-2.15.2.ja
 r lib/jackson-annotations-2.15.2.jar lib/jackson-core-2.15.2.jar
```

including the Scala runtime and the declared dependency on Jackson.

Comment: Great response. So the way is to implement it by yourself. :(
In your implementation, jar in Provided scope are also added. I tried by filtering by scope, but looks like dependencyClasspathAsJars does not has that information. How can I do it?

Comment: I tried with this `def exceptProvided(cp: Classpath): Classpath = cp.filterNot(_.get(moduleID.key).exists(_.configurations.contains("provided")))` but unfortunately it doesn't work, all dependencies are reported with `default` configuration instead of `provided`, not sure why.